# Command to view containing folder of an application in Ubuntu

Tags: 13.04, command-line, 13.10, directory

Which command is used to view containing folder of an application? For example, I installed Emacs, Chrome,... on my computer, now I want to view folder that holds them. How can I do that via terminal? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the right answer.
You should try to use command: `dpkg -S <package name>` from terminal.

Answer (score 3):

There are three ways to figure this out:

This one is Debian/Ubuntu specific: `dpkg -L <package name>` and lists all files installed by that package.

But you can also use `whereis <cmd>` to list all files and folders containing that cmd-name, or to just locate the executable file: `which <cmd>`. Both these commands work on almost any Linux distro.